# Convert day of year to date assuming all years are non-leap years

Tags: r, date, dataframe, as.date

I have a df with year and day of year as columns:

```
dat <- data.frame(year = rep(1980:2015, each = 365), day = rep(1:365,times = 36))
```

Please note that I am assuming 365 days in a year even if it is a leap year. I need to generate two things:

1) month
2) date

I did this:

```
# this tells me how many days in each month  
months <- list(1:31, 32:59, 60:90, 91:120, 121:151, 152:181, 182:212, 213:243, 244:273, 274:304, 305:334, 335:365)

library(dplyr)
# this assigns each day to a month
dat1 <- dat %>% mutate(month = sapply(day, function(x) which(sapply(months, function(y) x %in% y))))
```

I want to produce a third column which is a date in the format `year,month,day`.
However, since I am assuming all years are non-leap years, I need to ensure that my dates also reflect this i.e. there should be no date as 29th Feb.

The reason I need to generate the date is because I want to generate number 
of 15 days period of a year. A year will have 24 15-days period

```
    1st Jan - 15th Jan: 1 period 
    16th Jan- 31st Jan: 2 period 
    1st Feb - 15th Feb: 3 period....
    16th till 31st dec: 24th period)
```

I need  dates to specify whether a day in a month falls in the first 
half (i.e.d day <= 15) or second quarter (day > 15). I use the following
script to do this:

```
dat2 <- dat1 %>% mutate(twowk = month*2 - (as.numeric(format(date,"%d")) <= 15))
```

In order for me to run this above line, I need to generate `date` and hence my question.

Comment: [My answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49031624/r-generate-which-15-days-period-a-day-fall-into) seems relevant here as well.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have used the last bit of the question from your solution to my previous post. The only thing that I did not have was to convert day of year to date. Now I have combined below answer to your solution to get what I wanted.

Comment: The answer below also converts day of year to a sequence of values in a parseable format, but using `strptime` instead ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
dat$dates <- as.Date(paste0(dat$year,'-',
                            format(strptime(paste0('1981-',dat$day), '%Y-%j'),
                                   '%m-%d'))
                     )
```

What this does:

- With `strptime(paste0('1981-',dat$day), '%Y-%j')` you get the dates of a non-leap year.
- By embedding that in `format` with `'%m-%d'` you extract the month and the day in the month.
- `paste` that together with the year in the `year`-column and wrap that in `as.Date` to get a non-leap-year date.